# 400 Bad Request error with HTTP multipart request

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I am trying to hit 1 API, making an HTTP POST request using multipart data, but I am getting 400 Bad Request Error.

```
var reqPayload='{
    "param1":"value1"
}';

var ajaxOptions = {
            url: href,
            type: method_NAME,
            async: true
};
ajaxOptions.data = new FormData();
ajaxOptions.data.append("jsonInputParameters", $.parseJSON(reqPayload));

ajaxOptions.contentType = false;
ajaxOptions.processData = false;

//following will not create any problem since there is only 1 file.
$.each($('#id_NAME input[type="file"]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    ajaxOptions.data.append('primaryFile', file);
});
```

**My request looks like this:**

```
------WebKitFormBoundary9hoSobTAHgGksFST
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="jsonInputParameters"

[object Object]
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="primaryFile"; filename="example.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

------WebKitFormBoundary9hoSobTAHgGksFST
```

**But, what I want is this:**

```
------WebKitFormBoundary9hoSobTAHgGksFST
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="jsonInputParameters"

{
"parentID":"FB4CD874EF94CD2CC1B60B72T0000000000100000001"
}

------WebKitFormBoundary9hoSobTAHgGksFST
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="primaryFile"; filename="example.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

<File Content>
------WebKitFormBoundary9hoSobTAHgGksFST--
```

Please let me know some work-around to issue this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `reqPayload` variable is a string, so you don't need to serialise it at all; you can just append it to the `FormData` as-is:

```
ajaxOptions.data.append("jsonInputParameters", reqPayload);
```

That said, it's much better practice, and easier to maintain, if you create the payload as an object and then use `JSON.stringify` to serialise the data before making the request, like this:

```
var reqPayload = {
    param1: "value1"
};
ajaxOptions.data.append("jsonInputParameters", JSON.stringify(reqPayload));
```

Comment: But, variable reqPayload is already in string format. So, how can this help ?

Comment: Also, I need to send object instead of String

Comment: Good point. In that case just append it straight to the FormData without any encoding.

Comment: You cannot send an object in a HTTP request, it has to be serialised to a string

Comment: Thanks a ton, Rory. Just passing the String worked. I was trying to pass the info as Object for a long time. Thanks a lot.